# Parsing Date from MongoDb in Flutter always fails

Tags: mongodb, flutter, datetime

I'm trying to parse a `Date signUpDate` field from MongoDb User object received via http request into a Flutter `DateTime signUpDate` but it always fails. In my User Schema I have `signUpDate: { type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now },`. In my Flutter `factory User.fromMongoDB(Map<String, dynamic> map)` helper I'm using `signUpDate: DateTime.parse(map['signUpDate'])`. When printing http response `signUpDate` is `"signUpDate":"2021-12-15T11:10:01.521Z"`. Is it just the format coming back from mongo not parsable by DateTime parser or I'm parsing it wrongly?
Many thanks.

Comment: In mongoDB strored in iso8601, you need to convert the iso8601 string to data time.

Comment: @JahidulIslam when reading from `map['signUpDate']` is just a String , how to I converti it to  an ISO 8601 Sting?

Comment: please check my answer @vincenzo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the code for parsing ISO8601 string to Date time just passing what format you need.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var data = "2021-12-15T11:10:01.521Z";

  DateTime dateTime = getFormattedDateFromFormattedString(
      value: data,
      currentFormat: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ",
      desiredFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  
  print(dateTime); //2021-12-15 11:10:01.000
}

getFormattedDateFromFormattedString(
    {required value,
    required String currentFormat,
    required String desiredFormat,
    isUtc = false}) {
  DateTime? dateTime = DateTime.now();
  if (value != null || value.isNotEmpty) {
    try {
      dateTime = DateFormat(currentFormat).parse(value, isUtc).toLocal();
    } catch (e) {
      print("$e");
    }
  }
  return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I wasn't expecting to have to writhe a decoding method.. so I think I'be better off using millisecondsSinceEpoch then for easy read/write from/to Mongo. Many thanks again for the help!