# Flutter DateFormat class doesn't convert

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I got date input in text field using showdatepicker, convert it to string and input it to `Date = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(PickedDate.toString());` and need output date in format dd-mm-yyyy. I tried printing the `Date` but I got terminal output as `0008-12-12 00:00:00.000` why it doesn't work, how do I solve this

```
TextField(
                  onTap: () async {
                    DateTime? PickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                        firstDate: DateTime(2010),
                        lastDate: DateTime(2026));

                    if (PickedDate != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        paidDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy')
                            .parse(PickedDate.toString());
                        print(paidDate);
                      });
                    } else {
                      Get.snackbar('Error', 'Pick paid date',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red);
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

Comment: you may try out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362855/parsing-date-from-mongodb-in-flutter-always-fails/70363163#70363163)

Answer (score 0):

with the print function the date gets printet with the default format with is `0008-12-12 00:00:00.000`. To get the `dd-MM-yyyy` format you havt to print the datetime like this:

```dart
   print(DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(paidDate));
```

Comment: ```.format()``` return date in string, but I want data in ```DateTme``` data type to upload it in firebase so, I used ```.parse()```.

Comment: is the date in the console correct apart form the format. If not can you send the string you are trying to prase.

Comment: No, picked date and date in console are different.